# what is the equivalenet tag for ROWSPAN in table layout in android

Tags: android, html, tablelayout

what is the equivalent tag for ROWSPAN in table layout in android

for COLSPAN = layout_span is working fine

Comment: Elements can't span multiple rows, so there is no row span

Answer (score -5):

go to layout xml and add to appropriate element property adnroid:layout_span="number_of_columns_to_span"

Comment: The OP asked about row span, not column span.